# I crossed two wires, and fried my circuit. How do I test for parts that need replacing? (I'm new to this, schematic included)

Tags: circuit-analysis

I built a metal detector with the Surf Pi 1.2 kit. [This guide](http://www.adrianandgenese.com/blogger/2012/07/13/how-to-build-a-surf-pi-1-2-pulse-induction-metal-detector-from-a-diy-kit/) was a big help.

This was my first project outside of soldering two wires together, definitely a learning experience. Probably a little more advanced than I should have gone.

Everything was working, until I accidentally crossed the speaker wire with the coil wires while adjusting my coil's sensitivity. There was a spark, and the sound coming from the speaker got very loud, and then died (forever). Below is the schematic, and I've noted the two wires that got crossed in red.

[image: Surf pi metal detector circuit. Crossed wires boxed in red.]

- Note that I already tried a new speaker. Still dead.

I now have two questions:

1. What could I expect to find wrong? What typically gets fried first?
2. How can I go about testing the parts? And will I need to unsolder them to test?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you fried only the transistor and maybe the mosfet. The speaker is probably good. you can disconnect both the transistor and the mosfet or eventually speaker and coil and measure with an ohmmeter the resistance between drain and source or collector emitter. if you find a short, the part is broken.

Comment: Tony, verify also the potentiometer because it could be open. The value should be variable between 0 ohm and 1 k